# ¿Por qué me sale System.FormatException: 'La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.'?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

lo que sucede es que estoy tratando de crear un factura y a la hora de calcular el total que es el precio (label15) por la cantidad (textBox1) pero me sale el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y que hay en el label? (seguro no es un numero, si no que tiene formato) o que hay en textbox1? (mismo tema)...

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que cuando intentas convertir el texto de la Label o el TextBox a float, no llegan números (o por lo menos, no llegan solo números).

En este caso concreto, el float.Parse() pide un string por parámetros (que es el 'textBox1.Text' que le estás pasando, o lo mismo para la Label). Lo que va a hacer el Parse, es intentar interpretar ese texto como números, y cambiar el tipo de dato. Pero el problema es que no consigue 'formatear' el texto, porque puede que no contenga números, que los números vengan acompañados de texto, o que el texto esté vacío, mismamente.

Podría ser válido: "12345", "0", ...
Es inválido: "nums162738", "123abc", " ", "",...

Como ves, pueden pasar muchas cosas, pero todas relacionadas con que en el float.Parse() no estás pasando un texto que contenga única y exclusivamente números.

Saludos!